# iPhone view with vertical letter scroll bar (like Contacts/FB Friends view)

Tags: iphone

Any recommendations on what UIView to use on the iPhone to create a listed sorted alphabetically with a vertical scrollbar that has letter on it, similar to the Contacts application or Friends in the Facebook iPhone app?

Either a three20 view or a stock UIView from UIKit will work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for a list like in the Contacts application, this is just a standard UITableView afaik.

You can use this UITableViewDelegate method and return an array that will be displayed in the index list to the right:

```
 - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

You can also use `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` to get the bold/regular text style the contacts app uses.

Documentation: [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)